# Select Control Id is still the same even though already add clientidmode="Predictable"

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, html

I am trying to insert new Select control every time i add new row in DataGrid but with different id. My problem is why the id is the same for all control in different row in the same DataGrid? i am using this code to add the select control

```
<select id="Matches" clientidmode="Predictable" multiple="multiple" onclick="MatchSelected(event, this);" onblur="HideMatches(event, this);" onkeydown="LeaveWhenEsc(event, this);"></select>
```

I am referring to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx) examples.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Remove clientidmode it will generate unique

Answer (score 0):

It turns out i forgot to input runat="server". So it will not process the clientidmode.